# How to jump to 'input' bar in a website dictionary with shortcut in Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

In website dictionaries such as Cambridge,Oxford,and Merrian-Webster Dictionary.Is it a must to use mouse to jump to the search input bar
? How to achieve it with keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

For me, these sites seem to load with the cursor already in the search field. However, if this isn't your experience, I would press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key on your keyboard as this will move the cursor for you.